# How to read number data with strings placed at random line-intervals?

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files

I have a data file that consists of lines of space separated numbers (four columns), with at non regular intervals some text.
[Here's](http://pastebin.com/tBX70mRu) an example data file. I want to extract the parts that have four columns of numbers.

How can I skip over the text and read only the numbers?
I tried using textscan:

```
filename = 'data.dat';
inputfile = fopen(filename);
delimiter = sprintf(' '); 
numberdata = textscan(inputfile, '%f%f%f%f','delimiter', delimiter);
fclose(inputfile);
```

I thought `textscan` would ignore all data that would not fit the specified format, however this is not the case.
It just returns with empty arrays.

Comment: Please give some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always `regexp`, which happily ignores non-matching text.

### Standard decimal format

Consider a character array, delimited by newlines:

```
>> nums = '2.7183 3.1416 0.7071';
>> txt = 'asdf. blah, blah...';
>> contents = strjoin({nums,txt,nums,nums,txt},'\n')
contents =

2.7183 3.1416 0.7071
asdf. blah, blah...
2.7183 3.1416 0.7071
2.7183 3.1416 0.7071
asdf. blah, blah...
```

Apply `regexp` with [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html), which operates on cell arrays:

```
>> str2double(reshape(regexp(contents,'(\d+\.?\d*)','match'),3,[])')
ans =
    2.7183    3.1416    0.7071
    2.7183    3.1416    0.7071
    2.7183    3.1416    0.7071
```

BUT, the numbers must have a digit before the dot (e.g. `1.`) or it will match a dot in the irrelevant string line.

### Scientific (exponential) notation

For your data, where numbers look like `-8.673617380E-19`,

```
fid = fopen('tBX70mRu.txt','r');
fullContents = char(fread(fid))'; fclose(fid); %' uint8 converted to string
pattern = '-?\d*\.\d*E[\+|\-]\d{2}';
allNums = str2double(reshape(regexp(fullContents,pattern,'match'),4,[])')
```

Matches perfectly. Verify with `format longe`.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tinkering I came up with the following solution.
It first reads in all the data line-by-line to a cell array, then checks that cell array line-by-line if the line starts with a digit or with a dash (all desired numbers in my data file do) and writes it to an array.

```
% Read in everything line-by-line
filename = 'data.dat';
fid = fopen(filename);
tline{1} = {fgets(fid)};
i = 1;
while ischar(tline{i}{1})
    i = i + 1;
    tline{i} = {fgets(fid)};
end
fclose(fid);

% Sift out number data
j = 1;
for i = 1:length(tline)
    if ((isstrprop(tline{i}{1}(1),'digit')) || (strcmp(tline{i}{1}(1),'-')))
        numberdata(j,:) = sscanf(tline{i}{1},'%f %f %f %f');
        j = j + 1;
    end
end
```

It works, but I have the feeling this is not optimal.

Comment: After seeing your data, I updated my answer for the scientific E notation you are using.